# How to tell Windows Boot Manager (bootmgr) to load and execute the 1st sector of a specified partition ( chainload )?

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have 2 old-style MBR partitions (non-GPT, non-EFI):

1. An "active" partition containing `Windows 7 OS` and its `bootmgr` - the Windows Boot Manager and its BCD..
2. The second partition contains an exotic non-Windows OS, which has its own
   bootloader code in its **Partition** Boot Record (PBR/VBR) - the 1st sector of the 2nd partition (512 bytes).

I can successfully boot the Exotic OS through the Windows7's Boot Manager (bootmgr) by creating a Boot Menu entry with the following steps:

```
Copy the first sector of the Exotic OS' partition into the file named `exotic.bin` in the Windows7's filesystem.
Execute:
     bcdedit /create /d ExoticOS /application bootsector  
     bcdedit /set {**guid**} device partition=c:  
     bcdedit /set {**guid**} path \exotic.bin
```

However, this method of booting is imperfect because the Exotic OS often updates its own boot sector (in the 1st sector of its own partition) and then the file `exotic.bin` becomes outdated.

I tried:

```
bcdedit /create /d ExoticOS /application bootsector
bcdedit /set {**guid**} device partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
```

...and these commands executed successfully, but I do not know how to specify the 1st **sector number** on this partition.

QUESTION: How to instruct the Windows Boot Manager (bootmgr) to load & execute the Exotic OS' boot sector, **DIRECTLY** from the 1st sector of the 2nd partition - not from the outdated copy `exotic.bin` ?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following commands at the `Windows 7` command prompt:

```
     bcdedit /create /d ExoticOS /application bootsector  
     bcdedit /set {**guid**} device partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
     bcdedit /set {**guid**} path :512
     bcdedit /displayorder {**guid**} /addlast
```

Where the `{* * guid * *}` denotes the 32 character `GUID` in curly braces that has been returned by the `bcdedit /create ...` command and the `\Device\HarddiskVolume2` is the identifier of the partition which has the `Exotic OS` installed.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1058217/list-every-device-harddiskvolume/) for a guide how to find out this partition identifier. 

The string `:512` means "load the first 512 bytes of the specified partition ...and execute it".

For this to work, you must replace the file `bootmgr` on your Windows startup partition with the `bootmgr` available [here](https://gofile.io/?c=DdZLZh).

Comment: This method of booting ( chain loading the Volume Boot Records `VBR`s ) can also work with Windows 8 and 10.  However for those versions of Windows, a newer version of the versatile  `bootmgr` file needs to be used.  Reply if you need it.